# npm start failed to compile only in a specific folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-package

I have installed node.js for learning. I have created my very first project in the following path "C:/Programming/React.js/test". Now, when I tried `npm start` it shows the following:

```
Failed to compile.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "C:\\Programming\\React.js\\test\\node_modules\\.cache" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
 - configuration.module.rules[1].oneOf[3].include: The provided value "C:\\Programming\\React.js\\test\\src" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "C:\\Programming\\React.js\\test\\build" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
```

(Note that I have created a separate folder for all my projects)

I also have another project in this "C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/my-app" path. But when I try to run `npm start` in that folder, it works.

Here are my `package\.json` for both of my projects.

Project - test:

package.json

[package.json - test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VINA.png)

Project - my-app:

package.json

[package.json - my-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6jrQ.png)

P.S. I'm new to react and stackoverflow. If something is missing in my question, please let me know and I'll update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when you have an exclamation mark somewhere in your folder path. Considering the error message you provided, you don't have any of them.

You can try this:

1. **If you configured webpack manually**, then check your `webpack.config.js`  (or whatever you named your configuration file) on presence of exclamation marks. You can't use them when declaring a path (neither in folders nor in files names). You can also provide your `webpack.config.js` here, probably it will help to detect an error.
2. **If you created your app using create-react-app**, try to go to `/node_modules` and delete `.cache` folder. If it doesn't help - maybe you should rename your folders or just create a new project. Probably something simply went wrong when this one was creating.